# What is incorrect about searcing for `?:((xxxx)|(yyyy)|(zzzz))+` in `x = y + z`

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Code:

```
import re    
r = re.search("?:((xxxx)|(yyyy)|(zzzz))+", "x = y + z")
```

Error message:

```
D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/ghqer4tqaery.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/ghqer4tqaery.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = re.search("?:((xxxx)|(yyyy)|(zzzz))+", "x = y + z")
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 199, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 302, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You have made a typo by swapping `?:` and `(`.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression begins with the `?` meta-character. `?` means "the preceding thing zero or one times". If you put a `?` at the beginning of the regex, then there is, as the error claims, nothing to be repeated zero or one time, so the regex is invalid.

Rearranging the regex to `(?:(xxxx)|(yyyy)|(zzzz))+` would cause the `(?:` to be interpreted as a non-capturing group as I presume you intend.

Answer (score 0):

> `?` : Matches the **preceding** subexpression zero-times or once.

---

Is this you want?

```
import re    
r = re.search("(?:(x))|(?:(y))|(?:(z))+", "x = y + z")
print(r.groups())  # But re.search() will only return the first successful matched result
```

or find all Variables in the equation？ Like this:

```py
import re    
r = re.findall(" *([xyz])+ *", "x = y + z", re.I)
print(r)
```